# form does not submit after validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, kendo-ui

When the form is submitted, the alert Hooray! fires when validation is true, but the form does not actually submit. If I replace the form with @using (Html.BeginForm()) it does but the kendo validation does not work?

```
 <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h2 class="ra-well-title">Your Details</h2>


    <form id="ticketsForm">
        <div class="form-horizontal form-widgets col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="fname">First Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.firstName, new { @class = "input k-textbox", placeholder = "Enter Firstname", required = "required", validationmessage = "Required", id = "pFirstName", onchange = "OnChangeEventpFirstName()" })
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="name">Last Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
                    @(Html.Kendo().TextBox()
                          .Name("surName")
                      .HtmlAttributes(new { placeholder = "Last Name", required = "required", validationmessage = "Enter Lastname", id = "pSurName", onchange = "OnChangeEventpSurName()" })
                    )
                </div>


            </div>


            <input type="submit" value="Send Booking" class="btn k-button" onclick="return confirm('Ready to send Booking?')" />
    </form>


    <script>
        $(function () {
            var validator = $("#ticketsForm").kendoValidator().data("kendoValidator");
            var status = $(".status");

            $("form").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (validator.validate()) {
                    alert("Hooray! Your tickets has been booked!")
                        .removeClass("invalid")
                        .addClass("valid");
                } else {
                    alert("Oops! There is invalid data in the form.")
                        .removeClass("valid")
                        .addClass("invalid");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>


</div>
```

Comment: when htmlbegin() did you include id too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `event.preventDefault`, which stops the form from submitting. You should move that line inside the `else` statement, so that it only stops the submission if the validation fails.

As to why your validation does not fire when you use BeginForm, most likely the form's ID was different or missing, so the JavaScript was not bound to the form.